# How to get MySQL to match `%D%` => `Đ`

Tags: mysql, unicode, collation

I have run into an extremely frustrating feature, for some reason a query involving select `LIKE %D%` will not match `Đ`.

All other characters that are like this do match, however. `%n%` matches `ñ`, `%o%` matches `ồ`, but if I am searching for `%Dong Nai%` I will not get `Đồng Nai`.

Although `%Thua Thien-Hue%` will match `Thừa Thiên-Huế`

Is this a MySQL feature or something hard coded into Unicode, or is there a way around this? It makes people who are using my website unable to find events about certain Vietnamese provinces, unless they have access to the `Đ` key, which virtually nobody in America does.

EDIT:

The fact that a, e, i, o, or u matches all Vietnamese vowels is very unexpected behavior to a Vietnamese speaker.

For reference; here are all the Vowels in Vietnamese.

à, á, ã̉, ạ, a, ằ, ắ, ẵ, ẳ, ặ, ă, ầ, ấ, ẫ, ẩ, ậ, â, è, é, ẽ, ẻ, ẹ, e, ề, ế, ễ, ể, ệ, ê, ì, í, ĩ, ỉ, ị, i, ò, ó, õ, ỏ ,ọ, o, ồ, ố ,ỗ, ổ, ộ ,ô, ờ, ớ ,ỡ, ở, ợ, ơ, ù, ú, ũ, ủ, ụ, u, ừ, ứ , ữ , ử, ự, ư

---

My question is then, 'What constitutes a different enough letter?'.

---

**It appears other Vietnamese speakers have reported this as a bug to MySQL:**

This behavior appears to not be present in 5.6+. I will let you know if an  update of MySQL helps.

http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=61258

Comment: Not sure if there is a solution... but in case you don't find anything better you could always use a `REPLACE` statement. Something like `SELECT field FROM column WHERE REPLACE(column, 'Đ', 'D') LIKE ("%D%")`

Comment: That's a possibility. Seems messy though

Comment: You need to adjust the collation that's being used so MySQL knows that it needs to match `D` and `Đ`. Googling and reading at MySQL site will tell you how to do that (it's not easy but not overly complex).

Comment: It's an ugly workaround, but what if you looked for `D` and modified your query? If the query text contains `D`, look for both `D` and `Đ`, query for `field LIKE '%Dong Nai%' OR field LIKE '%Đong Nai%'`

Comment: What's your encoding set?  Utf-8 or ISO?  Which ISO?  Latin-1, Latin-9 ??

Comment: Utf-8 general is the encoding set

Comment: @David Yaw: it's more or less what I was proposing, but `REPLACE` makes the query more general.

Comment: Fair enough for Vietnamese to report it as a bug, but what about Icelandic or Serbian people (among a few others), also using this character Đ, probably not pronouced the same anyways ?

Comment: Hi, my Mysql version is 5.6.17 still cant match D with Đ. Is there any solution??

Answer (score 2):

It is to do with the collation. Check out http://www.collation-charts.org/mysql60/ and you will see that D and the character Đ are not the same when it comes to comparison. As suggested by nico in the comments the easiest (although not the fastest) way round this would be to replace Đ with D when doing the comparison. However this may not be practical depending on your performance criteria in which case you may want to keep a separate column or table of content that has been adjusted to replace certain characters at the time of inserting the data into the database.

Comment: "D and the character Đ are not the same when it comes to comparison"  I think this is pretty much what I said too.

Comment: Oddly enough, I can't find the majority of Vietnamese vowels anywhere on there.

Answer (score 1):

Those Vietnamese vowels and their diacritical variants are primarily equal (have the same base character) but are secondarily (diacritical) different. Using the appropriate collation can make them equal.

However, this is different for 'D' and 'Đ' as they are not related characters and not equal by any collation rules. As such, compare to both letters is required.

[Implement Vietnamese Collation in MySQL](http://vietunicode.sourceforge.net/howto/vietcollationmysql.html)

Answer (score 0):

As in MySQL 8.0 with `utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci` collation, '%D%' can now match with 'Đ'.

Answer (score -1):

It's kind of normal, because Đ isn't equal to D anyways (you wouldn't want to do this correlation)...

D with stroke (Đ, đ) is used in Vietnamese, some South Slavic (e.g. Serbian), Moro and Sami languages.  It's not only a "kind" of D as it's pronouced differently...

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eth

In other words...  Finding a record containing Đ when you search for D *wouldn't* be correct.  It would be like getting a dollar sing $ when searching for S.

Comment: Again, running into the same problem of 'Why does it match some distinct letters?'

Comment: I guess because it matches when it's supposed to (close enough)...  When you look for a dollar sign ($) you wouldn't want MySQL to return words with S.  I guess it's the same thing here...

Comment: I suppose, although back to Vietnamese '%Thua Thien-Hue%' => 'Thừa Thiên-Huế' is there a reference of "close enough letters"?

Comment: I'm no Vietnamese specialist, but I'm pretty sure that the D -> Đ is just like c- > ¢ difference...  Even if it *looks* alike, it's completely different.

Comment: being a native french-speaking, I can say that e, é or ê are very similar, waaay more that a dollar sign $ and the letter S...  Another distinction of Đ is that it's used in 3 or more different languages, with different meaning...  É or Ë will pretty much mean the same thing in each language using it...

Comment: Agreed; since dollar sign makes no sound. This comparison is outlandish. It is more like comparing two kinds of hyphens. However, in Vietnamese these two letters are entirely different vowels, each vowel e|ê can carry one of 5 accents. The e's: e, ẹ, ẻ, ẽ then the ê's: ê, ệ, ế, ề, ể, ễ, However, to a Vietnamese speaker this behavior is unexpected, that 'e' matches ALL of them, because e and ê are totally different. Like S and Z.

Comment: @ecchymose: Depending on the language accents are not *simply decorative* characters, they completely change the meaning of the word. Also, forgetting about accents, the behaviour of MySQL with the pairs `c/ç` and `n/ñ` is unconsistent with `Đ/D`

Comment: @nico: I know they aren't decorative, as I said, being french-speaking I know the difference between É, Ê or normal E...  I don't know Vietnamese (don't speak it) but what I read about was that Đ isn't an accent version of D.  While É is a variant of E and Ç is a variant of C...  Đ isn't simply a variant/accent of D.  (just like $ isnt a variant of S - I know this example looks weak, but for english-speaking persons it's the closet example I could find). Also, as I said, the Đ character isn't only used in Vietnamese, but in 2-3 different other languages.

Comment: Being a Vietnamese-speaking, Vietnamese use 'D' for searching words contain either 'D' or 'Đ'.